# Excel Change Events

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I've been trying to build a file that auto-populates some Cells based on specific rules, upon selection from a drop down list. I've been experimenting with the worksheet_change trigger and have come with the following

```
    Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Target.Address = "$C$4") Then
Range("$D$4").Value = Range("$M$8").Value
Range("$E$4").Value = Range("$N$8").Value
Range("$F$4").Value = Range("$O$8").Value

End If

If (Target.Address = "$C$5") Then
Range("$D$5").Value = Range("$M$9").Value
Range("$E$5").Value = Range("$N$9").Value
Range("$F$5").Value = Range("$O$9").Value
*Where M/N/O have vlook-up formulas.

End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that the file could have an upwards of 200 entries and its hard to scale this code to that size, especially since I have to update three V-look-up formulas for each target cell.[Excel File Screenshot](https://ibb.co/hRTLGp3)

I'm quite new to VBA so any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @cybernetic.nomad suggested, I would use `offset` in this case because your destination cells are always copied from the cell 4 rows down and 10 to the right.

My different take on it though is to make sure the `Worksheet_Change` event is only triggered when the cells in column C (or third column) are changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = 3 Then
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(4, 10)
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = .Offset(4, 11)
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = .Offset(4, 12)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

More information on the `offset` property can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset

**Edit:**
And as @BigBen commented on the other answer, you can set `EnableEvents` to false before the values are set and true after they are copied. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents)

**Edit 2:** 
Although originally stated that `EnableEvents` isn't entirely needed for this example, as @Mathieu Guindon pointed out, by leaving it out then any future changes to the code or spreadsheet could have the change events cause undesirable consequences.

For clarity, `EnableEvents` would be placed as so. I have also included`Resize`, as @VBasic2008 suggested, for further simplification:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = 3 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False 'Stop the change event being triggered on the following copying of values
            .Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = .Offset(4, 10).Resize(1, 3).Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True 'Make sure we turn it back on
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is correct you could simplify with `.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = .Offset(4, 10).Resize(1, 3).Value`.

Comment: Disabling app events will make debugging much, much easier, since the handler scope will otherwise be re-entered 3 times every single time `Target.Column = 3`. Hard disagree that it isn't needed: an accidentally re-entering handler is just a bug waiting to cause problems. Disable app events, don't have a re-entrant handler, avoid the headaches when (not if, *when*) that code needs to change in the future.

Comment: Both good points - I agree with both. Yes - using `Offset` with `Resize` is more simple - I thought for the purpose of helping relate to the OP question, it might be slightly easier to follow keeping it split-out. And with Disabling app events - on reflection, I think I will edit the answer to take this point into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The relative position of the ranges seems to be constant in your example, assuming this is always true, you can use `Offset`

```
Dim MyTarget as Range

MyTarget = Target

MyTarget.Offset(1,0).Value = MyTarget.Offset(4,10).Value
```

Comment: Also probably needs `EnableEvents` turned off otherwise this'll be an infinite loop.

Comment: `MyTarget` being a `Range` object, the `MyTarget = Target.Address` assignment to a `String` value would be a *type mismatch* error. EDIT: no wait, that's an implicit default member assignment against a null reference, so it's error 91.